# Calling External Command using 'for' or 'While' loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python programming language. I am trying to call external command (VMAX Storage symcli cmd) using Python loop. The external command should run for each item in the list, with input from the list. How do I make this work?

```
import subprocess

SG = ["PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4"]

for i in SG:
    print(i)
    subprocess.run("symsg -sid 73 show SG[i]")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Why is this tagged python-2.7, you're using Python 3, no? By the way, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation.

Comment: Firstly, you're missing a quotation mark which is messing up your code. ```SG = ["PC1","PC2","PC3",PC4"]``` -> ```SG = ["PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4"]```

Comment: Read about string formatting: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html

Comment: @rao2020 The `'SG[i]'` part in your argument to `subprocess.run` is not being interpreted as an entry in your `SG` array, its being treated literally as a string. You need to use string formatting as suggested above. Given that `i` is already a string, its as simple as `'"symsg -sid 73 show " + SG[i]'`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses folks.
@PaulRooney Thanks for the response. It makes sense. I have tried '"symsg -sid 73 show " + SG[i]' but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @LapisRose both of them look same to me. Did I really miss the quotation mark?

Comment: I edited the quotation mark back in, reasoning that it was a typo in your question rather than a code error. The code obviously wouldnt run at all if that quote wasnt there.

Answer (score 0):

Been awhile since I used subprocess. You can checkout the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) about how to use subprocess. It looks like you need to put the arguments in a list and seperate them. I ran this quick test on windows and it worked.

```
from subprocess import run

test = run(['ipconfig', '--help'])
print(test)
```

**EDIT**

Based on a comment below about using the questions actual command. Here is my attempt at it. I wasn't able to test this command to verify it worked since I don't have `sysmsg`.

```
from subprocess import run

test = run(['symsg', '-sid', '73','show', SG[i]])
print(test)
```

Comment: Wouldn't your answer be better if you showed how to do it with his actual command line?

Comment: Good point. I tried it with the actual command. I wasn't able to test it though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks for the valuable feedback. I found the solution. it's working with the below code.

import subprocess

SG = ["PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4"]

for i in SG:
    print(i)
    subprocess.call("symsg -sid 73 show " + SG)